# How to optimize code of comparison between a list and strings through stdin - performance is important

Tags: python, hadoop

Right now i have a script that receives strings from stdin and i have also a list which is about 70mb on disk (in many partial files) which i load into memory into one list.

I then search each string as it comes in from stdin and search if it exists in the list. I understand this is slow because of the huge list and the number of strings that can also be a great amount that come in.

It goes like this:

```
def buildindex():
    # j = 0
    # while j < len(parts_list):
        # f = urllib2.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/source123/output/" + parts_list[j])
    j = 0
    while j <= 200:
        if j < 10:
            f = urllib2.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/source123/output/part-0000" + str(j))
        if j < 100 and j >= 10:
            f = urllib2.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/source123/output/part-000" + str(j))
        if j >= 100:
            f = urllib2.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/source123/output/part-00" + str(j))

        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.rstrip()
            yield line
            print line
        j += 1
        f.close()

linelist = list(buildindex())

for suspicious_line in sys.stdin:
    if "," in suspicious_line:
        suspicious_key, suspicious_source, suspicious_start, suspicious_end = suspicious_line.strip().split(",")

        x=re.compile(suspicious_key)
        sub_list = filter(x.match, linelist)
        # do something
```

I tried to run this locally and its been over 20 minutes and its still going. Also i will use these scripts on Amazon EMR (hadoop) and it also fails for some reason. If i try a subset of the list, it works.

What performance wise changes can i make to keep things neat and relatively fast?

Comment: What is the format of `suspicious_key`? Is it really a regex? Also, what are you using as stdin?

Comment: ah suspicious key is something like this `ATTGACGTAG` 10-characters long in this case,its not a regex but its something that i try to filter my list with, is it wrong to do so? (my list contains something like this per line - `10 char word, document-name, number, number` hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem maybe not in `for suspicious_line in sys.stdin` block, but in the `build_index`. Reading files from s3 can be slow. Have you timed `buildindex`? Run the script without the `for suspicious_line in sys.stdin` block and see how much time it takes.

If `buildindex` is the problem, download the files to the disk.

If `buildindex` is **not** the problem, you can try using the "simpler" filter `in` instead of regex (creating a regex is expensive)

```
sub_list = [line for line in linelist if suspicious_line in line]
```

Comment: It takes around 5 minutes. So it should not be that part that is not efficient.

Comment: I will try that and get back to you, i hope it makes a significant difference ;o